# SEGFAULT when creating own index in postgresql for POINT3DZ

Tags: postgis, postgresql, c

I'm trying to write my own index for 3d points - POINT3DZ (using pgis and postgres 9.4). I have written a code similar to `spgquadtreeproc.c` [1]

This is my `spg_quad_point3dz_picksplit` function:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(spg_quad_point3dz_picksplit);
/* Decides how to create a new inner tuple over a set of leaf tuples. */
Datum
spg_quad_point3dz_picksplit(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS){
    spgPickSplitIn *in = (spgPickSplitIn *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    spgPickSplitOut *out = (spgPickSplitOut *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(1);
    int i;
    POINT3DZ centroid, ctemp;

#ifdef USE_MEDIAN
    /* Use the median values of x and y as the centroid point */
    POINT3DZ      **sorted;

    sorted = palloc(sizeof(*sorted) * in->nTuples);
    for (i = 0; i < in->nTuples-1; i++){
        datumGetPoint3dzP(in->datums[i], sorted[i]);
    }

    centroid = palloc(sizeof(*centroid));

    qsort(sorted, in->nTuples, sizeof(*sorted), x_cmp);
    centroid->x = sorted[in->nTuples >> 1]->x;
    qsort(sorted, in->nTuples, sizeof(*sorted), y_cmp);
    centroid->y = sorted[in->nTuples >> 1]->y;
#else
    /* Use the average values of x and y as the centroid point */

    for (i = 0; i < in->nTuples; i++)
    {
        datumGetPoint3dzP(in->datums[i],&ctemp);
        centroid.x += ctemp.x;
        centroid.y += ctemp.y;
    }
    centroid.x /= in->nTuples;
    centroid.y /= in->nTuples;
#endif

    out->hasPrefix = true;
    out->prefixDatum = (Datum)&centroid;
    out->nNodes = 4;
    out->nodeLabels = NULL;     /* we don't need node labels */
    out->mapTuplesToNodes = palloc(sizeof(int) * in->nTuples);
    out->leafTupleDatums = palloc(sizeof(Datum) * in->nTuples);

    for (i = 0; i < in->nTuples; i++)   {
        POINT3DZ p;
        datumGetPoint3dzP(in->datums[i], &p);

        int quadrant = getQuadrant(&centroid,&p);

        out->leafTupleDatums[i] = (Datum)&p;
        out->mapTuplesToNodes[i] = quadrant- 1;
    }

    PG_RETURN_VOID();
}
```

Constans `USE_MEDIAN` is not defined so in the function are executed lines from top of function, next - lines from else to endif, and finally rest of code. Unfortunately first for loop work fine, but second take an error on executing `datumGetPoint3dzP`.

This is how the `datumGetPoint3dzP` function looks inside:

```
void datumGetPoint3dzP(Datum dt, POINT3DZ *p){
    GSERIALIZED *geom;
    LWGEOM *lwgeom;
    LWPOINT *point = NULL;
    geom = (GSERIALIZED *)PG_DETOAST_DATUM(dt);
    if ( gserialized_get_type(geom) != POINTTYPE )
        lwerror("Argument to X() must be a point");
    lwgeom = lwgeom_from_gserialized(geom);
    point = lwgeom_as_lwpoint(lwgeom);
    getPoint3dz_p(point->point, 0, p);
}
```

I found in debugging that an error occurs while calling `getPoint3dz_p`.

`getPoint3dz_p` is a function from PostGIS (lwgeom) [2]

ERROR:

```
CREATE INDEX example_sensors_index1 ON sensors_data USING spgist( geom geometry_point3dz_ops );
DEBUG:  StartTransactionCommand
DEBUG:  StartTransaction
DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children: 
DEBUG:  ProcessUtility
DEBUG:  Creating index "example_sensors_index1" on table "sensors_data"
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

LOGS: 
Some of the messages are in Polish. To everyone I posted a translation under the message.
Here is a part of my logs: https://pastebin.com/dYyb0tFb

How do I fix this code?

links:
[1] 37.187.79.115/postgresql-9.4beta3/src/backend/access/spgist/spgquadtreeproc.c
[2] http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_acfc410375b25ddd41feec1b7337173c6.html

Comment: Since this touches on some heavy database stuff, you might have some luck trying the DBA Stackexchange as well https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql or even the postgres mailing list.